# Angular 9 unrecognized expression routerlink

Tags: javascript, html, css, angular, angular-router

I'm building an Angular 9 application where I'm facing two issues.

1) While I change the routes from my navbar I'm getting an error about unrecognized expression like below in my console, although the routes are changing successfully. I've tried various ways to solve it but have failed so far.

> Syntax error, unrecognized expression: /about

2) A part of the h1 tag on my landing page is changing which I've achieved using data-period and data-type attributes. But once I change the routes the h1 data array stops changing when I again hit back to the landing page till I refresh the landing page from the refresh button again and it starts working as it should. Here is my [github repository](https://github.com/tridibc2/demo) in case you want to check
navbar.html:

```
<nav class="navbar navbar-expand-lg navbar-light bg-light header-sticky">
    <div class="container">
        <a class="navbar-brand" routerLink="/"><span>E</span>xample</a>

        <button class="navbar-toggler" type="button" data-toggle="collapse" data-target="#navbarSupportedContent" aria-controls="navbarSupportedContent" aria-expanded="false" aria-label="Toggle navigation">
            <span class="navbar-toggler-icon"></span>
        </button>

        <div class="collapse navbar-collapse" id="navbarSupportedContent">
            <ul class="navbar-nav ml-auto">
                <li class="nav-item"><a routerLink="/home" class="nav-link">Home</a></li>
                <li class="nav-item"><a [routerLink]="['/about']" class="nav-link" href="#about">About</a></li>
                <li class="nav-item"><a [routerLink]="['/services']" class="nav-link" href="#services">Services</a></li>
                <li class="nav-item"><a [routerLink]="['/contact']" class="nav-link" href="#contact">Contact</a></li>
                <li class="nav-item"><a class="nav-link" href="#blog">Blog</a></li>
            </ul>
        </div>
    </div>
</nav>
```

Module.ts:

```
import { NgModule } from '@angular/core';
import { CommonModule } from '@angular/common';
import { Routes, RouterModule } from '@angular/router';
import { FormsModule, ReactiveFormsModule } from '@angular/forms';

import { ClientRoutingModule } from './client-routing.module';
import { BlogHomeComponent } from '../blog-home/blog-home.component';
import { ContactComponent } from '../contact/contact.component';
import { HomeComponent } from '../home/home.component';
import { ServicesComponent } from '../services/services.component';
import { AboutPageComponent } from '../about-page/about-page.component';

const routes: Routes = [
    {path: '', component: HomeComponent},
    {path: 'home', component: HomeComponent},
  {path: 'blogs', component: BlogHomeComponent},
  {path: 'services', component: ServicesComponent},
  {path: 'about', component: AboutPageComponent},
  {path: 'contact', component: ContactComponent}
];

@NgModule({
  declarations: [
    HomeComponent,
    AboutPageComponent,
    BlogHomeComponent,
    ServicesComponent,
    ContactComponent,
    AboutComponent,
  ],
  imports: [
    RouterModule.forChild(routes),
    CommonModule,
    ClientRoutingModule,
    FormsModule,
    ReactiveFormsModule
  ],
  exports: [RouterModule]
})
export class ClientModule { }
```

Landing page HTML:

```
<div class="main-banner item-bg-one" id="home">
    <div class="creative-banner-three"></div>
    <div id="particles-js"></div>
    <div class="d-table">
        <div class="d-table-cell">
            <div class="container">
                <div class="main-banner-text">
                    <h4>Create a <span>Buzz</span></h4>
                    <h1>Promote Your
                    <!-- Problem is over here -->
                        <a href="" class="typewrite" data-period="2000" data-type='[ "Business.", "Branding.", "Social Media." ]'>
                        <span class="wrap"></span>
                        </a>
                    </h1>
                    <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit, sed do eiusmod tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua.</p>
                    <a href="#welcome" class="btn btn-primary">Book a free session</a>
                    <a href="#work" class="btn btn-primary view-work">View Pricing</a>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

app.module.ts

```
import { BrowserModule } from '@angular/platform-browser';
import { NgModule } from '@angular/core';
import { HttpClientModule } from '@angular/common/http';
import { RouterModule } from '@angular/router';
import { BrowserAnimationsModule } from '@angular/platform-browser/animations';
import { ReactiveFormsModule, FormsModule  } from '@angular/forms';
import { ToastrModule } from 'ng6-toastr-notifications';
import { AppRoutingModule } from './app-routing.module';
import { AppComponent } from './app.component';
import { NavbarComponent } from './shared/navbar/navbar.component';
import { FooterComponent } from './shared/footer/footer.component';
import { PreloaderComponent } from './shared/preloader/preloader.component';
import { PageNotFoundComponent } from './page-not-found/page-not-found.component';
import { ClientModule } from './client/client-routing/client.module';
import { NgModule } from '@angular/core';
import { Routes, RouterModule } from '@angular/router';
import { PageNotFoundComponent } from './page-not-found/page-not-found.component';
const routes: Routes = [{path: '**', component: PageNotFoundComponent}];
@NgModule({
    declarations: [
        AppComponent,
        PreloaderComponent,
        NavbarComponent,
        FooterComponent,
        PageNotFoundComponent],
    imports: [RouterModule.forRoot(routes),
        ClientModule,
        HttpClientModule,
        BrowserModule,
        BrowserAnimationsModule,
        FormsModule,
        ReactiveFormsModule,
        AppRoutingModule,
        ToastrModule.forRoot()],
     providers: [],
    bootstrap: [AppComponent],
    exports: [RouterModule]
})
export class AppModule{ }
```

ClientModule.ts

```
import { NgModule } from '@angular/core';
import { CommonModule } from '@angular/common';
import { FormsModule, ReactiveFormsModule } from '@angular/forms';
import { Routes, RouterModule } from '@angular/router';
import { ClientRoutingModule } from './client-routing.module';
import { ContactComponent } from '../contact/contact.component';
import { HomeComponent } from '../home/home.component';
import { ServicesComponent } from '../services/services.component';
import { AboutPageComponent } from '../about-page/about-page.component';

const routes: Routes = [
    {path: '', component: HomeComponent},
    {path: 'home', component: HomeComponent},
{path: 'services', component: ServicesComponent},
  {path: 'about', component: AboutPageComponent},
  {path: 'contact', component: ContactComponent}
];

@NgModule({
  declarations: [
    HomeComponent,
    AboutPageComponent,
    ServicesComponent,
    ContactComponent
  ],
  imports: [
RouterModule.forChild(routes),
    CommonModule,
    ClientRoutingModule,
    FormsModule,
    ReactiveFormsModule
  ],
exports: [RouterModule]
})
export class ClientModule { }
```

Comment: Why you have binded routerLink to an array?

Comment: no I didn't..I've declared routerLink in two ways as routerLink="/home" and [routerLink]="['/home']" but both are returning the same error

Comment: look, use angular's own router, instead of other method. go to app-routing.module.ts , just page routes there and import the components also, and you can then use it anywhere [ i repeat : do not go inside app.module.ts ]

Comment: can you post your main route file here?

Comment: @CodeMind done..check now

Comment: i cant see any route file been attached

Comment: Issue is due to the jquery sizzle

Comment: @Piyush how do I solve that?

Comment: @CodeMind I got a different child module where I have all the routes written which is called in app.module.ts. Check now I've updated with both the module

Comment: @chatterjeetridib it would take time to debug this issue, will try to debug once I get time.

Answer (score 0):

For the First Part, you should remove `href="#about"` because we should not use `href` and `routerLink` together. Normally Href is using for external links.

For the second part, I think angular it not recognizing your changes. So you should it force it to check if there is a change like this by :

Add to the imports of your components:

```
  ChangeDetectorRef from '@angular/core';
```

Add to Your Constractor:

```
private changeDetector: ChangeDetectorRef
```

Refresh after a value or something change.

```
  // now notify angular to check for updates
  this.changeDetector.detectChanges();
```

Comment: I removed the href tag but still getting same error. After adding the ChangeDetectorRef I'm now getting another error as ASSERTION ERROR: Should be run in update mode [Expected=> false == true <=Actual]

Comment: After removing Href it should work without any problem! are you sure all the hrefs are removed? -- second part I think there is miss place code check this link: https://github.com/angular/angular/issues/32756

Comment: now the links in my navbar are like  this   <li class="nav-item"><a routerLink="/home" class="nav-link">Home</a></li>     but still getting same error. Please have a look at my repository